# I am a newb to JSON, and am trying to build a multiple page AJAX form with it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

I apologize for sounding daft in advance, but I recently discovered JSON in Rails and I'm really interested in creating a form that is broken up through several pages. The data would then be carried from page to page through a JSON object.

I'm stuck on how to properly to do that.

My first page of the form is this :

## First Page

**Controller:**

```
def create
  # removed some code here for the sake of simplicity
  if @card_signup.save
    respond_to do |wants|
      wants.html {}
      wants.json { render :json => { :html => (render_to_string :partial => 'final_form')}}
    end
  else
    respond_to do |wants|
      wants.html { render :new }
      wants.json { render :json => { :errors => @card_signup.errors } }
    end
  end
end
```

**The Javascript that handles saving the first form to this controller**

```
$(".step_two_submit").click(function(){

  $("#new_card_signup").attr("action", function(index, action) {
    var values = [],
        getKey;

    $("#sortable").sortable('serialize').replace(/(\w+?)\[]=(\d+?)/g, function(all, key, number) {
        values.push(number);
        getKey = key;
    });

    var cardSignupGetParams = 'card_signup=' + getKey + '[' + values.join(', ') + ']';
    return action + '?' + cardSignupGetParams + "&foo[]=bar";
  });

});
```

Here's the tough part! I want to make it so that I validate if this form was written correctly as usual. No problem, the form is set up to do that. But when they click next, I want them to go to **a second** form which is a *disclaimer* they have to agree to before the Object is saved.

So if they back out, or don't approve of the disclaimer, the Object will have never been created.

To accomplish this.. I assume I need to instead of *saving* the object, I need to *store* the object in a JSON object and carry it over via AJAX to this next AJAX loaded disclaimer page.

Does anyone know how I might be able to splice that together?

Again, I apologize if this doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want to do is validate the object before you go to the second part of the page.  If you definitely want to make a round trip to the server, you can use `@card_signup.valid?` instead of `@card_signup.save` in the controller of your "check" action, and then just hide the form elements with javascript and show your disclaimer.  This way you are still checking that it *would* save when it's finally submitted, but not actually saving it into the database.

Another way to do this without javascript would be to have the first page submit to the controller action that just checked for a valid object, and go to a second page which then renders most of the form elements as hidden elements, effectively carrying the filled-in form to the second page without saving it.

Alternately, you can do the validation on the client side as much as possible and not hit the server.  See the [Client Side Validations](http://railscasts.com/episodes/263-client-side-validations) railscast for an interesting and easy-ish way to get this done.

Comment: I guess my question was more in line with how to transfer the json object from controller action to action. I'm not really sure how to do that, or what its syntax would be.

Comment: That question doesn't make sense.  What do you mean from controller action to action.

Comment: Cool jamuraa, I ended up doing what you said, and it did help in the long run. I was kind of hung up on how the AJAX was to be put together more technically. I look forward when Rails incorporates aJAX more into its system.